# How to disable Shared Mono Runtime by not using the Android Options?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin project that was successfully building APKs when I was using VS 2019 v16.9

After I've updated my VS to v16.9.1, I started getting an error:
"Shared Mono runtime is enabled for (name of project)"
I tried to follow the recommendations of others who have faced the same issue but it seems that the option to disable "Use Shared Mono Runtime" is missing in the new update.

[image]

Is there any other way to disable Shared Mono Runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could edit the .csproj file directly. Unload the project then make the changes in that file by hand then reload the project.

[image: csproj example]

Comment: could you help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66651260/choosing-proper-technology-for-building-multi-platform-application-for-both-desk